# Creating a dictionary of lists from nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

How do I create a dictionary of lists from uneven nested lists with a list of keys?
I tried the dictionary comprehension but it doesn't come out right.

Assume this is the list:

```
value_list = [['this is news head', 'abstract of the news', 'link of the news', ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', ... 'title10' ]],['this is news head2', 'abstract of the news2', 'link of the news2', ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', ... 'title10' ]]]

key_list = ['head', 'abstract', 'link', 'titles']
```

I tired this:

```
d = {k: value_list[i::3][i::10] for i, k in enumerate(key_list)}
```

but it doesn't give me this output:

```
output: [{'head':'this is news head', 'abstract':'abstract of the news', 'link': 'link of the news', 'titles': ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'...'title10']},{'head':'this is news head2', 'abstract':'abstract of the news2', 'link': 'link of the news2', 'titles': ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'...'title10']}]
```

Comment: Your expected output does not make sense. It looks like you want a set of lists, with the _lists_ to contain key-value pairs, but this is not how lists work. Did you actually want a _list of dictionaries_?

Comment: You are right, I was on the fence with the structure of it when I was writing it down. So, I have now changed it into a list of dictionaries. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're doing the fancy indexing.  this is all it takes.

```
d = [dict( zip(key_list, v)) for v in value_list]
```

So, for each row, I create a zipped list of pairs matching the value to the key, and then convert that to a dict.

Output:

```
[{'head': 'this is news head', 'abstract': 'abstract of the news', 'link': 'link of the news', 'titles': ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title10']}, {'head': 'this is news head2', 'abstract': 'abstract of the news2', 'link': 'link of the news2', 'titles': ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title10']}]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the great and speedy answer. Really appreciated.